# Windows.Forms load element after Radio Button is checked

Tags: winforms, powershell

I am trying to create a `Windows.Form` with PowerShell, where a group of check boxes only appears when a specific radio button is checked.

Comment: SO is not a place where other people write code for you. Show us what you have tried (i.e. show your code) and explain what is not working as you expected, and we'll help you improve/fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the `CheckBox` object's visibility with the `Visible` property:

[image: Now you see it]

[image: Now you don't]

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

#region ConditionalCheckBoxes
# Create a bunch of CheckBoxes and set their visibility to hidden 
$CheckBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$CheckBox1.Text = "Option 1"
$CheckBox1.Visible = $false
$CheckBox1.Top = 50
$CheckBox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$CheckBox2.Text = "Option 2"
$CheckBox2.Visible = $false
$CheckBox2.Top = 75
$CheckBox3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$CheckBox3.Text = "Option 3"
$CheckBox3.Visible = $false
$CheckBox3.Top = 100
#endregion

#region RadioToggleGroup
$RadioToggleGroup = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Panel
#endregion

#region RadioToggleOn
$RadioToggleOn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$RadioToggleOn.Text = "Show"
$RadioToggleOn.Left = 10
# Make sure checkboxes are made visible when clicking the radio button
$RadioToggleOn.Add_Click({
    $CheckBox1.Visible = $true
    $CheckBox2.Visible = $true
    $CheckBox3.Visible = $true
})
$RadioToggleGroup.Controls.Add($RadioToggleOn)
#endregion

#region RadioToggleOff
$RadioToggleOff = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
# Make sure checkboxes are hidden again
$RadioToggleOff.Text = "Hide"
$RadioToggleOff.Top  = 25
$RadioToggleOff.Left = 10
$RadioToggleOff.Add_Click({
    $CheckBox1.Visible = $false
    $CheckBox2.Visible = $false
    $CheckBox3.Visible = $false
})
$RadioToggleGroup.Controls.Add($RadioToggleOff)
#endregion

$CheckBox1,$CheckBox2,$CheckBox3,$RadioToggleGroup |% {$Form.Controls.Add($_)}
$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Similarly, you could put all the `CheckBox` objects inside a `GroupBox` or `Panel` and control the visibility of just that